# How can i tell ibuffer to show me only the useful columns?

Tags: ibuffer

How can i tell ibuffer to show me only the useful columns?

[image]

Comment: if you're a veteran emacs user and have stopeed using stock ibuffer display, what package have you migrated in to? and does it address the problem described

Comment: `C-h v ibuffer-formats` should allow you to customize it.

Comment: And `ibuffer-switch-format` (bound to backtick by default) toggles between the two default formats, the second of which excludes the size and mode columns.